# Having trouble in the setCoordinates function

Tags: reactjs, getter-setter

I am a newbie in React JS and I am following the below tutorial (application 1):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDa8kZLNhJ4&list=PL6QREj8te1P6wX9m5KnicnDVEucbOPsqR&index=10

Specifically from timestamp 56:37.

I have two files, App.js and Map.js

App.js code is as follows:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { CssBaseline, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import {getPlacesData} from "./api";

import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import List from './components/List/List';
import Map from './components/Map/Map';

const App = () => {
    const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);

    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({});
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {      
        getPlacesData()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setPlaces(data);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
            <Header />
            <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ width: '100%'}}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                    <List />

                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
                    <Map
                        setCoordinates = {setCoordinates}
                        setBounds = {setBounds}
                        coordinates = {coordinates}

                    />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code for Map.js:

```
import React from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import { Paper, Typography, useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";
import LocationOnOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LocationOnOutlined";
import { Rating } from "@material-ui/lab";

import useStyles from "./styles";

const Map = ({coordinates, setCoordinates, setBounds}) => {
  console.log(coordinates)
  console.log(setCoordinates);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 600px)");

  //const coordinates = {lat: 0, lng: 0}
  return (
    <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "API KEY" }}
        defaultCenter={coordinates}
        center={coordinates}
        defaultZoom={14}
        margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
        options={{}}
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
          setCoordinates({ lat: e.center.lat, lng: e.center.lng});
        }}
        //onChildClick={""}
      >

      </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

I had initially set coordinates to:

`const coordinates = {lat: 0, lng: 0}`

When I had done that, I was getting my google map component rendered on the web-app and it was centered on lat: 0 and lng: 0.

Then I followed the tutorial and made the changes up to 59:58.
After doing so, the map component was not being rendered.
I did some console log and found out that the 'setCoordinates' function was not working and 'coordinates' was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the `coordinates` is empty but there is no problem with `setCoordinates` because it never executed.

The reason is that you did not initialize the initial `coordinates` and it's just an empty object and the map never shows up so you never changed the map and `onChange` function never executed.

**The Solution**

```
const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({lat: 0, lng: 0});
```